# ANON Apex Compile Error

Tags: apex, webservices

I am getting this weird error.

This is my code.

```
String AUD_Value, INR_Value;
Double AUD_d, INR_d, ftor;

HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
req.setEndPoint('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD');
req.setMethod('GET');

HTTP h = new HTTP();
HTTPResponse resp = h.send(req);
System.debug('Response Status : '+resp.getStatus());
System.debug('Response Status Code : '+resp.getStatusCode());
System.debug('Response Body : '+resp.getBody());
String response_string = String.ValueOf(resp.getBody());

JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response_string);
while(parser.nextToken() ! = null)
{

    if(parser.getCurrentToken == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)
    {
        if(parser.getText() == 'AUD')
        {
         parser.nextToken();
         AUD_Value = parser.getText();
        }
        if(parser.getText() == 'INR')
        {
            parser.nextToken();
            INR_Value = parser.getText();
        }
    }
}

AUD_d = Double.valueOf(AUD_Value);
INR_d = Double.valueOf(INR_Value);

ftor = INR_d/AUD_d;

System.debug('AUD_Value : '+AUD_Value);
System.debug('INR_Value : '+INR_Value);
System.debug('AUD_D : '+AUD_D);
System.debug('INR_D : '+INR_D);
System.debug('ftor : '+ftor);
```

When I try to Execute the above code in Anon Apex, I am getting the following error

[image]

I checked my code and do not find any "!" mark at all.
Not sure why I am getting this error.

Can someone take a peek at this ?

Comment: You have `! = null` that should be `!= null` in your code.

Comment: You are right..tx

Comment: @KeithC Do you want to add an answer for this?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Done.

Answer (score 2):

You have `! = null` that should be `!= null` in your code.